# Hazelcast with Spring Boot 3 GraalVM Native NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Migrated a Spring Cloud Gateway project to Spring Boot 3.1.2 and the following native configuration

```
{
  "resources":{
    "includes":[
      {"pattern":"hazelcast.yaml"}
    ]}
}
```

Configured Hazelcast beans and they are found by GraalVM runtime search

```
public class CacheConfig__BeanDefinitions {

  public static BeanDefinition getCacheConfigBeanDefinition() {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(CacheConfig.class);
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(CacheConfig::new);
    return beanDefinition;
  }

  private static BeanInstanceSupplier<HazelcastInstance> getHazelcastInstanceInstanceSupplier() {
    return BeanInstanceSupplier.<HazelcastInstance>forFactoryMethod(CacheConfig.class, "hazelcastInstance", Config.class)
            .withGenerator((registeredBean, args) -> registeredBean.getBeanFactory().getBean(CacheConfig.class).hazelcastInstance(args.get(0)));
  }

  public static BeanDefinition getHazelcastInstanceBeanDefinition() {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setTargetType(HazelcastInstance.class);
    beanDefinition.setDestroyMethodNames("shutdown");
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(getHazelcastInstanceInstanceSupplier());
    return beanDefinition;
  }

  private static BeanInstanceSupplier<Config> getHazelCastConfigInstanceSupplier() {
    return BeanInstanceSupplier.<Config>forFactoryMethod(CacheConfig.class, "hazelCastConfig", String.class, CacheConfigurationProperties.class)
            .withGenerator((registeredBean, args) -> registeredBean.getBeanFactory().getBean(CacheConfig.class).hazelCastConfig(args.get(0), args.get(1)));
  }

  public static BeanDefinition getHazelCastConfigBeanDefinition() {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setTargetType(Config.class);
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(getHazelCastConfigInstanceSupplier());
    return beanDefinition;
  }
```

Configuration class Hazelcast beans are configured in has `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`

hazelcast.yaml

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
```

However, when running the application the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[api-gateway:6.0.11]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.cache.HazelcastCacheMetrics.<init>(HazelcastCacheMetrics.java:79) ~[api-gateway:1.11.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: com.hazelcast.map.IMap.getName()String/invokeInterface
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hazelcast.map.IMap.getName()
```

I can't figure out when debugging a GraalVM application what one is supposed to do when confronted with `String/invokeInterface`.

Attempted to resolve by:

1. Included reachability-metadata which includes Hazelcast 5.2.1 runtime hints
2. https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html
3. Added

```
{
        "condition": {
          "typeReachable": "io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.cache.HazelcastCacheMetrics"
        },
        "name": " com.hazelcast.map.IMap",
        "methods": [
          {
            "name": "getName",
            "parameterTypes": []
          }
        ]
      }
```

From what I understand from the error, the issue stems from Spring Boot Actuator attempting to access Hazelcast cache statistics/metrics and being unable to find the IMap method.

I'm not sure how I can hint the runtime to be aware of this at build-time.

Comment: Hi @StevenPG did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing a similar issue with `NoSuchMethodException` for another method producerIndex

Comment: Unfortunately not @user2669657. We migrated over to Redis instead and used the tracing agent to generate metadata. We've had no problems since then. It's actually pushed us to migrate everything off of Hazelcast onto Redis.